# How to use BroadcastReceiver to handle multiple actions?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I am trying to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle multiple actions. The receiver is registered with an intent filter, but this restricts me of sending only one action type of intents to the receiver(see`Intent.getAction();`)

This is my `BroadcastReceiver` class and the way how I want to handle actions inside it.

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch(...){  //the criteria for switching to a particular case
                    ... //some cases to handle here
        }           
    }
}
```

The place where I register the intent looks like this(in the service class):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mbr = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(mbr, new IntentFilter("MyBroadcastReceiver"));
}
```

The way how I make a call looks like this(actually I just set a listener to a button):

```
   //creating the pending intent
   PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("MyBroadcastReceiver"), 0);
   //add button listener
   remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_button, myPendingIntent);
```

This way forces me to setAction("MyBroadcastReceiver") for each intent I want to pass to MyBroadcastReceiver.

However I want to pass intents that have **different actions**, how should I proceed?

Or this is not a good approach and is better to use for each different intent a separate `BroadcastReceiver` implementation with it's own `IntentFilter`?

Comment: cannot you just add another action to your `IntentFilter`?

Comment: If I am adding another Intent which has a different action than "MyBroadcastReceiver" it not caught by the broadcast receiver

Comment: because your `IntentFilter` has only one action associated with it: add another one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` can handle multiple actions, add them to the intent filter

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("action1");
filter.addAction("action2");
```

then register it with that filter

```
registerReceiver(mbr, filter);
```

and inside your own receiver switch for actions

```
switch(intent.getAction()){
    case action1:
        // do something
        break;
    case action2:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register one or more action for broadcast receiver using IntentFilter as below:-

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("Action1");
filter.addAction("Action2");
filter.addAction("Action3");

this.registerReceiver(mbr, filter);
```